# Firebase notification with user data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using firebase for my android studio app, and I would like to send notifications to users (I use JAVA). I started with FCM, however, it seems that I can only send a text that I write with it. I would rather send a notification to a specific user, containing his user data. How can I do that?

For example, as soon as my user reaches a score of 10, I want to send to him a notification saying congratulation, so a notification that would use the data from the database.

Comment: Please give some more information. But let me ask you first - why don't you send the notification via the app? Why do you need fcm for it? If you need fcm anyway: Do you also use Firebase Realtime DB or Datastore? If so, you could use Firebase Functions for this problem. Store the value for the trigger in the DB, store the fcm token of the user in the DB (please adjust DB access rules accordingly). Setup a trigger that will call the function. Let the function send a notification to the user via the API. It's all well documented.

Comment: I will need to set up "simple notifications" from the app aswell ^^ 
But I need to access the databse (firestore database) because that's where I store the "value" you mention. I've never use the "function" that you mention, is that what another comment is refering to ?

Comment: Check the docu: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions

Answer (score 1):

1. On server side initialize your FCM

```
    import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
    import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;

    File configFile = new File("your-project-firebase-adminsdk-123magic-chars456.json");
    String json = FileUtils.readFileToString(configFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes());
    
    FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(in))
            .build();
    
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

2. To send PUSH notification to specific user you need to know his registration token.

```
    import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
    import com.google.firebase.messaging.Message;
    
    //.......
    
    Message message = Message.builder()
        .putData("userId", ""+yourUser.getId())
        .putData("status", ""+yourUser.getStatus())
        .putData("score", ""+yourUser.getScore())
        .setToken(registrationToken)
        .build();
    String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
    
    Log.info(this, "SendPush to: " + yourUser + ", response: " + response);
```

3. On android app side. Add this to build.gradle (Module)

```
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
```

And this to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <service
        android:name="my.app.service.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

4. And now implement FirebaseMessagingService in your app. It does the following:

- receive PUSH-messages from your server,
- show notifications on device
- get registrationToken from FCM
- send token to server (where you can bind user with its token)

```
    package my.app.service;

    import android.app.NotificationChannel;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.RingtoneManager;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Build;

    import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
    import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver;
    import com.google.firebase.iid.internal.FirebaseInstanceIdInternal;
    import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
    import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
    import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

    import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

    import java.util.Map;

    import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
    import my.app.R;
    import my.app.MainActivity;

    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNewToken(String token) {
            
            // Send token to server here!
            
        }

        /**
         * Called when message is received.
         *
         * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
         */
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            String message = handleNow(remoteMessage.getData());

            // Check if message contains a notification payload.
            if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
                MyLog.info(this, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            }

            sendNotification(message);
        }

        



        /**
         * Handle time allotted to BroadcastReceivers.
         * @param data
         */
        private String handleNow(Map<String, String> data) {
            String userId = data.get("userId");
            String status = data.get("status");
            String score = data.get("score");
            
            // Here you can process message data as you wish

            String message = "Got data: userId=" + userId + ", status=" + status + ", score=" + score;
            return message;
        }


        /**
         * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
         *
         * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
         */
        private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
            Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera)
                            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                            .setContentText(messageBody)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                        "Channel human readable title",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }

            notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your very complete answer. I've having troubles to understand, you show some code that need to be "on server side".
Do I have to use "function" in firebase to do so ? It will take me time to fully understand your message, thank you very much

Comment: Sorry, I thought you have a backend server responsible for handling user data.

Comment: I have a backend with firebase / firestore. Your answer does not apply to that ?